# Native API to mount network volumes

Tags: macos, darwin

I'm looking for a native macOS API that would enable me to mount network volumes.

Specifically, I'm looking to do exactly what Finder (Cmd-K) does, including passing credentials separately from the URI and mountpoint creation under /Volumes without superuser access.

Currently I'm using `mount_smbfs` and `mount_afp`, but:

- They require credentials to be encoded into the URI, and `mount_afp` doesn't work with unicode characters in password, even urlquoted
- I have to create mountpoints as root first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NetFS framework and `NetFSMountURLSync()` or `NetFSMountURLAsync()`. The documentation is in the NetFS.h header file.